# Baby chillie buds are falling off

Tags: vegetables

I am from mumbai India now March month summer started. I watered[image] twice a week althoug my baby chillies are falling off after the polination, I used vermi compost as fertilizer.

Comment: Is twice a week enough? We (automatically) watered our Eggplants and Tomatos - both also nightshades multiple time a day [as dictated by amount if sunlight ] I syspect @winwaed is correct that maybe its to hot.

Answer (score 1):

I see this in Texas during the middle of summer - and always put it down to heat, as it happens even with lots of watering.  Some varieties handle the heat better than others (eg. 'Gypsy' bell does well for us).

I find fruiting is early summer before it gets too hot, and then from September through to the first frost. So during the summer heat,  I just keep them watered and make sure they grow, so I have nice large, healthy plants ready for when it cools sufficiently for fruit to form.